# LateInitializationError: Field '_splitScreenMode' has not been initialized flutter

Tags: flutter, runtimeexception

I'm facing this "LateInitializationError: Field '_splitScreenMode' has not been initialized." error, when I run the flutter app. can you help me?

Comment: please provide minimal reproducible code

Comment: Do you use ScreenUtil package?

Answer (score 0):

When working with the `late` keyword. You must initialize it before using it. Most of the time, you initialized it within the `initState`. Take a look at how I did it below:

```dart
    late bool _splitScreenMode; // I used bool type for this example

    // setting/initializing the _splitScreenMode
    @override
    void initState() {
        _splitScreenMode = true;
        super.initState();
    }
```

For more help with any questions, leave a comment below.

Comment: this solution is not working.

Comment: Hmm.. Impossible. Send your codebase here please.